# Is there any rule about the adjectives order?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

In English, adjectives are normally written in a specific order, for example [*colour, origin, material, purpose, noun*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1159/252).

> She liked to wear her red Spanish leather riding boots.

Is there a similar rule for Esperanto, or does Esperanto use a free-adjective-order as Italian?

Comment: I also wonder about affix order; *knabineto* for girleen, rather than *knabetino*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never heard of such a rule, I haven't found anything about it in PMEG and I can't remember hearing an adjective order that sounded weird to me. Use what feels natural to you.

Answer (score 0):

Oni diskutis tion antaŭ unu/du jaroj en Fejsbuka grupo. Certe neniu sciis pri firmaj aŭ oficialaj reguloj, sed sendube oni faras tiajn aferojn senpripense ankaŭ en Esperanto.

Kiun vi preferas?

- La granda nigra hundo
- La nigra granda hundo
- La hundo granda nigra
- La hundo nigra granda
- La granda hundo nigra
- La nigra hundo granda

Kelkaj el ili sonas bone, sed aliaj ne. Mi suspektas ke la "regulo" estas simila al tiu de la angla, sed ke la pli fiksitaj ecoj devas esti pli proksima al la substantivo. (Fakte, tiel estas ankaŭ en la angla).

En Esperanto oni foje rompas tiajn regulojn intence. Jen fama ekzemplo.

- Ne al glavo sangon soifanta ĝi la homan tiras familion.