# Ĉu ekzistas regulo por ordigi multajn adjektivojn en Esperanto?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

Kiam mi studadis la anglan, mi trovis regulojn por ordigi multajn adjektivojn rilate al unu substantivo. Tiam venis al mi la demando ĉu ekzistas iu ajn simila regulo por la Esperantaj adjektivoj.

Jen ekzemplo de l' angla adjektiv-ordo:

> Opinion - Size - Age - Shape - Colour - Origin - Material - Purpose - Noun

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of this question here: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/633/13

Comment: Yes probably. Too bad because this one was so nicely worded.

Answer (score 2):

Oni diskutis tion antaŭ unu/du jaroj en Fejsbuka grupo. Certe neniu sciis pri firmaj aŭ oficialaj reguloj, sed sendube oni faras tiajn aferojn senpripense ankaŭ en Esperanto.

Kiun vi preferas?

- La granda nigra hundo
- La nigra granda hundo
- La hundo granda nigra
- La hundo nigra granda
- La granda hundo nigra
- La nigra hundo granda

Kelkaj el ili sonas bone, sed aliaj ne. Mi suspektas ke la "regulo" estas simila al tiu de la angla, sed ke la pli fiksitaj ecoj devas esti pli proksima al la substantivo. (Fakte, tiel estas ankaŭ en la angla).

En Esperanto oni foje rompas tiajn regulojn intence. Jen fama ekzemplo.

- Ne al glavo sangon soifanta ĝi la homan tiras familion.